# ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0" postgresapp

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am running postgresapp 9.2.4.3 and postgis and trying to add a geometry column to a table. The postgis extension is running.

When I run:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public'::varchar,'gloutline'::varchar,'geom'::varchar,'4326','MULTIPOLY ON','2');
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE public.gloutline ADD COLUMN geom geometry(MultiP...
QUERY:  ALTER TABLE public.gloutline ADD COLUMN geom geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 110 at EXECUTE statement
SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)" PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I just unarchived the zip downloaded from postgresapp.com and dropped the .app in the applications dir.  postgresapp comes with postgis so no need for a postgis install.  CREATE EXTENSION postgis; executed with no issues. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

A reinstall of postgress.app including the application support files fixed the problem.

Comment: how did you force this reinstall ?